# Converting Map to Linkedlist hashmap adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, linked-list, hashmap

I have a LinkedList HashMap `List<HashMap<String, String>>`that I have created, I'm trying to send it to a custom adapter that I found but it is for a Map. What the best way to convert it to accept LinkedList Hashmap?

```
public class CustomListOutageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final ArrayList mData;

public CustomListOutageAdapter( List<HashMap<String, String>> map) {
    mData = new ArrayList();
    mData.add(map);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public HashMap.Entry<String, String> getItem(int position) {
    return (HashMap.Entry) mData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO implement you own logic with ID
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View result;

    if (convertView == null) {
        result = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mylistoutagedetails, parent, false);
    } else {
        result = convertView;
    }

    HashMap.Entry<String, String> item = getItem(position);

    // TODO replace findViewById by ViewHolder
    ((TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(item.getKey());
    ((TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.item)).setText(item.getValue());

    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding a Arraylist of HashMap you can create a Map[] array if you know the number of items

Comment: @L-X the items are coming from a web call in json format, so the number of items can be different each time

Comment: The data that you are getting from JSON is in which format is it a ArrayList or Map ??

Comment: @L-X I store it inside a HashMap and add that HashMap to List<HashMap<String, String>>

Comment: Well can you store your HashMap into ArrayList in your JSON Parsing logic, Because your CustomAdapter is using ArrayList
 of HashMap